# Traveling to US from France by ship

Tags: usa, france, ships

I would like to book a ship from France to US, hopefully Louisiana or Texas in the Spring. My fiancé has a health condition that prohibits air flight and I want to get him here as soon as possible to get him ready for surgery. How can I do this?

Comment: Scam alert. If you have not spent extensive amounts of time for real in person with this fiance, and most communications have been written/text and not voice or video, I would take an extremely skeptical view toward whether this is real.  Foreign scammers are *really, really, really good at this* - do not underestimate them.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Sorry, who is foreign in this story?

Comment: @Simd, while it is possible that the scammers are in and from the US, evidence has shown a lot more scammers in countries that are farther away, as to be harder to get in front of a judge when found out. I assume US scammers work often where they are foreign.

Comment: @Willeke I can’t tell from the question what the nationality is of the different parties. Also, why do you think they have just met?

Comment: @Simd, if you read my answer you can see I assume it can be a real situation with people who know each other well. But we have seen so many scams that we feel it is essential to warn about it. Asking for proof the person you are communicating with cost (almost) no money and little time. Being taken in by a scammer can cost huge amounts of money and cause a lot of distress. I know OP is in the US, fiancé is likely in France, no nationalities known for either, those are also not important.

Comment: You do realise that France has excellent hospital facilities? If your `fiancé` was to deteriorate in the middle of the Atlantic, then I doubt he would survive the journey. If they have proper health insurance, then the insurer would opt to pay for surgery in France rather than transport the person across the pond. Lastly, I doubt if shipping company would want to transport him on a 2 week journey if the person was that ill as their own insurance would not cover any issues. Lastly, there are special aircraft which can transport ill people which are pressurised above what they would normally be.

Comment: And if they don't have proper health insurance, they'd be better off paying for the work in France or Spain, *which are **vastly** cheaper than the US, like 1/3 to 1/20 the price*, which handily pays for the travel and lodging.  It's called "medical tourism". At the very least, hire your own US doctor to consult with your fiancé, not least because the doctor will be a lie detector.

Comment: The amount of people here who imagine they know the OP's situation is unbelievable. (1) There are many legitimate reasons to have a surgery in the U.S. rather than France such as, oh I dunno, having your family there to care for you. You also don't know what kind of insurance they have. (2) "Being ill" is not a single spectrum of "very ill" vs. "not very ill". There are many legitimate reasons why a person shouldn't fly but can spend 2 weeks on a ship such as, oh I dunno, having an issue with your ear. (3) It's entirely possible to need a surgery and not be in danger of rapidly deteriorating.

Comment: @Pilcrow  If it is legitimate then OP knows it's legitimate, I would not distrust someone I know deeply enough to marry just because of warnings online. If it isn't, romance scams are so prevalent and devastating to the victims and cost more loss monetary wise than any other types of scams in U.S. and Canada that I think it is more beneficial to post warnings than to simply ignore the usual warning signs present here: overseas, some kind of illness, excuses for not travelling to meet. And as you can see below, people are not just saying it is a scam but also answering in case it is legitimate.

Comment: @xngtng I wasn't talking about the warnings about a possible scam, which are reasonable. I was talking about people in the comments providing "advice" on how to handle an unknown health issue about which they know absolutely nothing at all other than the fact that a surgery is planned. For example, confidently advising the OP that their fiancé should stay in France without knowing literally anything about their situation at all.

Comment: Are you able to share the name of the condition ?

Comment: Would it hurt to either drop those details or tell us which  of them is really relevant to your travel plans, and then how?

Comment: He has a heart condition that would preclude him from flying due to the changes in pressure and such.  I had looked into cruise lines but none are traveling until May

Comment: @BeckyWilliams I know it may be obvious to you, but given the desire of people here to point out potential fraud and scams, you should explicitly confirm that this is a genuine relationship.

Answer (score 20):

You can take a trans-Atlantic cruise, or charter your own yacht/hitch a ride on a cargo ship. There are many cruises, but they may be slower and not necessarily convenient location or time-wise (here's an [example from Barcelona to New York](https://www.carnival.com/itinerary/15-day-transatlantic-cruise/barcelona/venezia/15-days/jt2/?itinportcode=bcn&military=N&pastGuest=N&senior=N&numGuests=2&evsel=J&hideSailingEvents=true&locality=1&currency=USD&sailDate=05292023&roomType=IS)). There's still a Trans-Atlantic passenger line [from Southampton to New York](https://www.seat61.com/queen-mary-2-transatlantic.htm), AFAIK that's the last one remaining.

You'll need to talk to private yacht owners or cargo shipping companies to arrange passage not on a generally available ticket. There are some potential websites which can facilitate that ([example](https://voyagesencargo.com/lines/liberty-bridge-usa-uk-netherlands)).

---

This, of course, under the assumption that the fiance actually exists, you've met them, know them personally, and trust them to be who they say they are. Most of the times "internet fiance" would be a scam.

Comment: There are sites where you can book on a cargo ship, almost cruise prices but other options for times.

Comment: @Willeke want to add a link?

Comment: No, as I do not know the sites but when you google 'cargo ship travel' or cargo ship cruise' you find them.

Comment: @littleadv Something akin to [CMA CGM offering](https://voyagesencargo.com/lines/liberty-bridge-usa-uk-netherlands) (not affiliated) but still that would arrive to 5k€

Comment: Thanks! Added as an example

Comment: I don't think cruise ships or cargo will allow passengers with severe health issues to come aboard, or probably with a accompanying nurse or medical person. (insurance issues)

Comment: Note: transatlantic cruises have stricter rules on health: medical evacuation is mostly impossible. But also cargo ships may require good health. And if it is urgent, why waiting spring? And why US which has the most expensive health care system? But if money is not an issue, you can get medical flights, which flight at low level (if necessary).

Comment: We have a ton of questions on cargo ship travels, see the [freighter-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freighter-travel) tag. Approaching shipping companies or trying your luck in harbours (as some other users have suggested in the past) is unlikely to work, you have to go through an agent but it is a well established process. Note however that these services stopped due to the pandemic and haven't resumed AFAIK.

Comment: @Max and Giacomo, shipping lines typically require some sort of health certificate. Traveling with a nurse is unlikely to help, the main risk is not the liability of the shipping line but the loss that would result from having to change the route of the ship and delaying delivery of its cargo. In fact, passengers are typically also required to buy a specific “deviation insurance” against this.

Comment: cruise ships are also famous for spreading illness!!  It is hard to imagine it is a good place for medically vulnerable people

Comment: An atlantic crossing with a private sailing yacht is only advisable if the person's health only doesn't allow flying (e.g.  due to low air pressure), but would still require quite a good physical condition. Not something I would expect when a surgery is planned. And it takes about 3 months(!) from France to the US.

Answer (score 18):

While there are *general* answers to your question (in addition to travel on freighters, there are cruise lines crossing the Atlantic), would any of them be safe for somebody with the health condition to allude to? And there are few medical procedures which are available in the US, yet unavailable in Europe.

I agree with littleadv, this smells of a romance scam.

Comment: Some medical procedures are approved in the USA and not in Europe, it's usually rare and mostly for rare and experimental procedures.

Answer (score 17):

Lets assume you have checked the person is really your fiancé and has indeed a health condition that prevents flying and is in need of surgery.

The next items on this list all have to been done, possibly some will require answers from others but the best way is likely to start them all as soon as you can.

- Consult with their current doctors what travel restrictions there are.
- Ask about surgery prognoses in their current location and near other locations like the next few countries.
- Inquire about the cost of treatment in both current location and near other locations and the US.
- Contact their health insurance whether they prefer to pay for the surgery and care around it in the US or where the patient is now.
- Contact your chosen transport company, which can be a cruise line, the cross Atlantic line ship company, a cargo company with passenger accommodation or an airline, whether they will take a passenger with these health conditions.

After you have gotten a few or all answers, contact your fiancé and ask them, pointing out advantages, disadvantages and costs.

It may well turn out that surgery in the US is not the only or even the best option.